# Vectorisation of complex function

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I'm trying to speed up some of my for loops using vectorisation. Unfortunately, the functions inside the loops are more complex than simple arithmetic operations. I want to take each item of an array, manipulate it using a function with multiple inputs, and then place it in the correct place in a dictionary. To do this, I have a function called increase_element:

```
def increase_element(number, word, factor=0.05):
    print(2.*factor)
    return {'factor': 2.*factor, 'number': number, 'word': word}
```

What I am trying to achieve is going from the array:

```
array([0., 0.1, 0.2])
```

to the array:

```
array([
       {factor: 0., number: 5, word: 'hi'},
       {factor: 0.2, number: 5, word: 'hi'},
       {factor: 0.4, number: 5, word: 'hi'}
      ])
```

in an efficient manner (i.e. not using a for loop) as in reality the function increase_element takes a long time to run.

What I have tried to do is use a function to convert all the inputs to a single input, then map this onto a numpy array as so:

```
import numpy as np

muls = np.linspace(0, 1, 11)

def increase_element(number, word, factor=0.05):
    print(2.*factor)
    return {'factor': 2.*factor, 'number': number, 'word': word}

def single_increase_element(inputs):
    return increase_element(inputs[0], inputs[1], factor=inputs[2])

single_array = np.array(list(map(lambda x: (5, 'hi', x), muls)))

np.array(list(map(single_increase_element, single_array)))
```

However I get the below error when trying to print 2.*factor

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Any advice would be great appreciated!

Comment: Incidentally, "currying" means something completely different from what you're doing. A curried version of `increase_element` would be called like `f(1)('two')(0.3)`, not like `f((1, 'two', 0.3))`.

Comment: Oh whoops! What's the name for what I'm doing?

Comment: I don't know if there is a name.

Comment: Well I've edited the post, thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the factor in your print is of type `<class 'numpy.str_'>`.
the error is because you are tring to multiple string with 2.0.

As for the code, I suggest you explain what you are trying to achieve because it is very complex to comprehend.

Edit: below it a your code fixed. The root cause was that dtype=np.object was missing and numbers were treated as strings.

```
import numpy as np

muls = np.linspace(0, 1, 11)

def increase_element(number, word, factor=0.05):
    print(2.*factor)
    return {'factor': 2.*factor, 'number': number, 'word': word}

def single_increase_element(inputs):
    return increase_element(*inputs)  # fixed
    # return increase_element(inputs[0], inputs[1], factor=inputs[2]) # original

# single_array = np.array(list(map(lambda x: (5, 'hi', x), muls)))  # original
single_array = np.array(list(map(lambda x: (5, 'hi', x), muls)), dtype=np.object) # fixed

np.array(list(map(single_increase_element, single_array)))
```

Comment: I've clarified my intention! I hope it's clear, if not let me know!

Comment: This should run faster if it stuck with lists.  Iteration on numpy arrays is slower.  And making an array from a list is time consuming.